# How to configure sound on Debian Bullseye on pi 4b

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

I just upgraded my raspberry pi os from Buster to Bullsye, and I have found that the audio is now working.  I right-clicked on the speaker icon on the taskbar and I got this.[image]

see the part on the top of the sound settings window where it says "Audio Card"? I go to that, select bcm2835 Headphones, and push close.  The audio still does not work.  I go to the audio settings again, to find the window looking like it does in the screenshot. No Audio Card stays selected, and no sound comes from the headphones when I try to use sonic-pi, or try to watch a youtube video, or run sauerbraten, or lmms.  No sound at all. I found that port audio is not installed. Will  installing it fix the problem?  If so, how do I install it? I looked around on the web, and found nothing at all on how to install it. How can I fix this problem of no audio?